# Convex Polygons, Graphics Algorithms

Tags: graphics, clipping, polygons, convex-polygon, planar-graph

Q.Why are convex polygons considered a better choice for designing graphics algorithms?

My A. Convex polygons are planar and easier to clip.

My answer is kind of brief and I am not sure if my answer is correct, can anyone else expand or give me a better answer for this question please?

Comment: What sort of graphics algorithms do you have in mind?

Comment: @Bart, what is your definition of *convex polygon*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is that convex polygons are easier to triangulate. Another is that it is easier to decide whether a point is inside or outside a convex polygon. Both tasks are important in graphics.